# Adding an image from a url - html

Tags: html, image

I am having trouble displaying an image from the internet on my html page.

The line is:

```
<img src="http://www.somepic..." alt="pic" />
```

What is wrong with it? Does that only work with images that are on my disk?

Thank you

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're having? This code looks fine to me, what is the url to the image that you're using?

Comment: any url, try :http://www.google.co.il/imgres?q=picture&hl=iw&sa=X&rlz=1C1SKPL_enIL452IL452&tbm=isch&prmd=imvnsl&tbnid=BAlLxbccyZkwSM:&imgrefurl=http://animal.discovery.com/mammals/cheetah/&docid=qDOKJbIkYvvzyM&imgurl=http://animal.discovery.com/mammals/cheetah/pictures/cheetah-picture.jpg&w=625&h=450&ei=Y-grT8_ZNYnntQb4kID0DA&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=693&vpy=191&dur=850&hovh=190&hovw=265&tx=155&ty=84&sig=110318714666115395229&page=1&tbnh=141&tbnw=183&start=0&ndsp=19&ved=1t:429,r:1,s:0&biw=1280&bih=656

Comment: @JamieDixon Yes I am too late to ask a question, I am facing this issue in one of my app. I am loading a JSP page where there is an image which gets loaded from some external website. When I first load the JSP page, it does not displays the image, when I copy the link from its source page and hit in another address bar, the image gets loaded and after this when I reload JSP page, image gets loaded. My problem is different. My question limit is reached so I am not able to ask a new question.

Comment: Are you checking CORS permissions?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Based on the URL you've presented in the comments above, my guess is that you're not actually linking to an image, you're liking to a web page but mistaking it for an image.

For instance, the url you provided:

http://www.google.co.il/imgres?q=picture&hl=iw&sa=X&rlz=1C1SKPL_enIL452IL452&tbm=isch&prmd=imvnsl&tbnid=BAlLxbccyZkwSM:&imgrefurl=http://animal.discovery.com/mammals/cheetah/&docid=qDOKJbIkYvvzyM&imgurl=http://animal.discovery.com/mammals/cheetah/pictures/cheetah-picture.jpg&w=625&h=450&ei=Y-grT8_ZNYnntQb4kID0DA&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=693&vpy=191&dur=850&hovh=190&hovw=265&tx=155&ty=84&sig=110318714666115395229&page=1&tbnh=141&tbnw=183&start=0&ndsp=19&ved=1t:429,r:1,s:0&biw=1280&bih=656

Is the URL of a webpage showing the image, not the image itself.

Make sure you're linking to the actual image itself:

```
<img src="http://animal.discovery.com/mammals/cheetah/pictures/cheetah-picture.jpg" 
alt="Cheetah!" />
```

Comment: … but don't hotlink images off other people's servers and don't infringe on their copyright.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add any url for image you will need to right click on that image and click on copy image address.
and paste that address as url to get image on your webpage

Answer (score 0):

my problem was that i forgot to include the quotes

DO THIS:

```
<img src="image.png" />
```

NOT THIS:

```
<img src=image.png /> //wrong!
```