# Showing Instagram photo in html img tag

Tags: html, image, url, instagram

When I use this URL in a browser I can see the photo https://www.instagram.com/p/CBqFrrCHVM7/media/?size=t

When using the same URL in an html img tag I have a broken img on the screen !

```
<img src="https://www.instagram.com/p/CBqFrrCHVM7/media/?size=t" alt="Broken !">
```

What am I doing wrong?

> **Just to let you know that without an adblocker that works fine !!! Thanks to all of you !**

Comment: The image url actually provides a redirect uri to the actual image. it could be mean that the server is selectively choosing whether to serve the actual image to servers but this doesn't seem to be the case as I tried the code on stackoverflow.com and cars.com and the image showed. Probably if you shared more code about the page this is on your server/network environment the stackoverflow community could provide a more detailed response.

Comment: ggordon : This is the code and the second photo show up from another website
`<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<img src="https://www.instagram.com/p/CBqFrrCHVM7/media/?size=t" alt="Broken !">
<img src="http://www.horse-ball.org/images_news/2020-06-03.jpg" alt="Not Broken !">
</body>
</html>`

Comment: Thanks for sharing the snippet, you could update your question with the updated snipped. I tested again, doesn't seem to be a code related issue. It even works from apps served from file:/// based urls

Comment: Thanks ggordon ! Tangu give me an answer and I do not know how to edit my own post !

Answer (score 1):

This is the right url

```
 <img src="https://instagram.fdla2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/e35/c73.0.554.554a/s150x150/105044346_127329445667781_2507554452160017737_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fdla2-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=109&_nc_ohc=Z6GCQyBWc5AAX8UqqUO&oh=10de7d78b17ad97d292104e42b2bbce7&oe=5F175C4E" alt="instagram">
```

someone already answered this kind of question before
[click here to see what he said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9129635/adding-an-image-from-a-url-html)

Comment: Tangu : OK I understand ;)) So how can show the real photo from the Instagram link with the img tag ?

Comment: <img src="https://instagram.fdla2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/e35/c73.0.554.554a/s150x150/105044346_127329445667781_2507554452160017737_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fdla2-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=109&_nc_ohc=Z6GCQyBWc5AAX8UqqUO&oh=10de7d78b17ad97d292104e42b2bbce7&oe=5F175C4E" alt="instagram">

Comment: WONDERFUL !!!! How you get it ? Because I'm using the script InstagramBasicDisplay.php (everything works fine) except 'media_url' who gives me the broken image ;((

Comment: do it like in the above comment bro

Comment: you can right click on an image the chose to copy image source to get the url

Comment: Tangu : Well I would like to do something automatic with InstagramBasicDisplay.php. But thanks it helped me to understand ;))

Comment: Tangu : The photo link given by Instagram is this one https://scontent-yyz1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/105044346_127329445667781_2507554452160017737_n.jpg?_nc_cat=105&_nc_sid=8ae9d6&_nc_ohc=ljLBtt3WWykAX-Z45pU&_nc_ht=scontent-yyz1-1.cdninstagram.com&oh=1f4d62340b1dd20549fdb291b88c8030&oe=5F13DD0D which is an image. But when I use this image (jpg) in my img tag I still have a broken photo !!!

Comment: Just to let you know that without an adblocker that works fine !!! Thanks to all of you !

Comment: Still doesn't work for me. I have `<img src="https://instagram.fisb1-2.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-19/s320x320/131440754_2827658134178690_2667946039001645763_n.jpg?tp=1&amp;_nc_ht=instagram.fisb1-2.fna.fbcdn.net&amp;_nc_ohc=4KXk6POZPKcAX9k-Qh9&amp;edm=ABfd0MgBAAAA&amp;ccb=7-4&amp;oh=5f0e4805830dc7dba2eb3ef42892d582&amp;oe=60B11CCE&amp;_nc_sid=7bff83" alt="instagram-image" >`.